# Gracenote/Cddb official genre list

Tags: python, gracenote

I am working with mp3s and metadata. I have used Python to edit and add metadata to each file, but I cannot seem to get genres to work. I have used Pygn, a gracenote module that seems to be doing its job well. The problem is with the gracenote data itself. When I request data for, say daft punk, `pygn.search(clientID=clientid, userID=userid, artist="Daft Punk", album="Random Access Memories")`
I am returned a JSON as expected. The problem is that the genre key gives me a text anwser, and a number such as 45720. I was wondering if maybe there is some Dewey decimal-like system in place here. Do you know what system this is? Do you have an official gracenote genre list?

Answer (score 0):

Gracenote does not provide genre list. But you can get the top level genre list of 25 genres through Rhythm API. Check out the [fieldvalues API call](https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api#createstation) on Gracenote Developer Program website.